# How can I ensure no repeated adjacent values in a table in a LUA code?

Tags: algorithm, lua

I'm currently working on an OpenVibe Session in which I must program a Lua Script. My problem is generating a random table with 2 values: 1s and 2s. If the value in table is 1, then send Stimulus through output 1. And if it's 2, then through output 2.

My question is how I can generate in Lua code a table of 52 1s and 2s (44 1s and 8 2s which correspond to 85% 1s and 15% 2s) in a way that you have at least 3 1s before the next 2s? Somehow like this: 1 1 1 **2** 1 1 1 1 1 1 **2** 1 1 1 1 **2** 1 1 1 **2**.

I´m not an expert in Lua. So any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Are repeated 2s allowed?

Comment: No, it must be 111 2 111 that means one 2s in between the 1s. Sorry if im not very clear

Comment: This is a math problem, not a Lua problem: you want a random partition of 44 into 9 parts such that all parts except that last are at least 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
local get_table_52
do
   local cached_C = {}
   local function C(n, k)
      local idx = n * 9 + k
      local value = cached_C[idx]
      if not value then
         if k == 0 or k == n then
            value = 1
         else
            value = C(n-1, k-1) + C(n-1, k)
         end
         cached_C[idx] = value
      end
      return value
   end
   function get_table_52()
      local result = {}
      for j = 1, 52 do
         result[j] = 1
      end
      local r = math.random(C(28, 8))
      local p = 29
      for k = 8, 1, -1 do
         local b = 0
         repeat
            r = r - b
            p = p - 1
            b = C(p - 1, k - 1)
         until r <= b
         result[p + k * 3] = 2
      end
      return result
   end
end
```

Usage:

```
local t = get_table_52()
-- t contains 44 ones and 8 twos, there are at least 3 ones before next two
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the help and specially @EgorSkriptunoff It was of great help!! Owe you BIG TIME! Thousand Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the logic.

You have 8 2s.  Before each 2 there is a string of 3 1s.  That's 32 of your numbers.

Those 8 groups of 1112 separate 9 spots that the remaining 20 1s can go.

So your problem is to randomly distribute 20 1s to 9 random places.  And then take that collection of numbers and write out your list.  So in untested code from a non-Lua programmer:

```
-- Populate buckets
local buckets = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
for k = 1, 20 do
    local bucket = floor(rand(9))
    buckets[bucket] = buckets[bucket] + 1
end

-- Turn that into an array
local result = {}
local i = 0
for bucket = 0, 8 do
    -- Put buckets[bucket] 1s in result
    if 0 < buckets[bucket] do
        for j = 0, buckets[bucket] do
            result[i] = 1
            i = i + 1
        end
    end
    -- Add our separating 1112?
    if bucket < 8 do
        result[i] = 1
        result[i+1] = 1
        result[i+2] = 1
        result[i+3] = 2
        i = i + 4
    end
end
```